# Comparing each element of 2 array lists Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a code that compares 2 arrayLists and return the deviation of the equal elements.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Ala");
        list.add("Asn");
        list.add("Ser");
        list.add("Thr");
        list.add("Ser");
        list.add("Tyr");

        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list2.add("Asn");
        list2.add("Ser");
        list2.add("Ala");
        list2.add("Thr");
        list2.add("Ala");
        list2.add("Trp");
        list2.add("Ser");
        list2.add("Tyr");

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0 ;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0 ;


for(int i =0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) { 
            String codoni = list.get(i);

            int j = 0;

            while(j < list2.size()) {
                String codonj = list2.get(j);

                if(codoni == codonj) { 
                    a = Math.abs(i-j);   
                        System.out.println("[ "+list.indexOf(list.get(i))+ " ] = [ " + list2.indexOf(list2.get(j)) + " ]"  +  a);

            }
            j++;                
            }           

        }

    }
}
```

So this code if u test it, it will output

```
[ 0 ] = [ 2 ]2
[ 0 ] = [ 4 ]4
[ 1 ] = [ 0 ]1
[ 2 ] = [ 1 ]1
[ 2 ] = [ 1 ]4
[ 3 ] = [ 3 ]0
[ 4 ] = [ 1 ]3
[ 4 ] = [ 1 ]2
[ 5 ] = [ 7 ]2
```

this means  `list.get(0) = list2.get(2)` and `list.get(0) = list2.get(4)`....

Now im trying to get the min(2,4) which is equals to 2 ... So I added this algorithme

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Ala");
        list.add("Asn");
        list.add("Ser");
        list.add("Thr");
        list.add("Ser");
        list.add("Tyr");

        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list2.add("Asn");
        list2.add("Ser");
        list2.add("Ala");
        list2.add("Thr");
        list2.add("Ala");
        list2.add("Trp");
        list2.add("Ser");
        list2.add("Tyr");

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0 ;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0 ;

        for(int i =0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) { 
            String codoni = list.get(i);

            int j = 0;

            while(j < list2.size()) {
                String codonj = list2.get(j);

                if(codoni == codonj) { 
                    a = Math.abs(i-j);   

                    b = b + a; 

                    c = b - a;

                    if (b != c) {

                        System.out.println("[ "+list.indexOf(list.get(i))+ " ] = [ " + list2.indexOf(list2.get(j)) + " ]"  +  Math.min(c, a));

                    }else if(codoni == codonj && i == j) {
                        System.out.println("[ "+list.indexOf(list.get(i))+ " ] = [ " + list2.indexOf(list2.get(j)) + " ]"  + a);
                    }

                }
            c = 0;  
            j++;                
            }           
            b = 0;

        }






    }
}
```

and I got this output

```
[ 0 ] = [ 2 ]0
[ 0 ] = [ 4 ]2
[ 1 ] = [ 0 ]0
[ 2 ] = [ 1 ]0
[ 2 ] = [ 1 ]1
[ 3 ] = [ 3 ]0
[ 4 ] = [ 1 ]0
[ 4 ] = [ 1 ]2
[ 5 ] = [ 7 ]0
```

instead of this I was expecting

```
[ 0 ] = [ 2 ]0
[ 0 ] = [ 4 ]2
[ 1 ] = [ 0 ]1
[ 2 ] = [ 1 ]0
[ 2 ] = [ 1 ]1
[ 3 ] = [ 3 ]0
[ 4 ] = [ 1 ]0
[ 4 ] = [ 1 ]2
[ 5 ] = [ 7 ]2
```

So when theres no repetition I have a 0 instead of `list.get(i) - list2.get(j)`

So Im trying to find a code that will return i-j when there's no repetition...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because your algorithm is broken. It works badly with repetitions too, because it's first result every time is 0.
It's because:

```
a = Math.abs(i-j); //get a value which is positive or 0
b = b + a; // sets value which is equals to 'a'
c = b - a; // get a value which is always 0 since a is positive or 0

if (b != c) {
    // finding minimum of 0 and 'a' where 0 will be the minimum every time
}
```

The correct algorithm:

```
int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String codoni = list.get(i);
    int j = 0;
    List<Integer> matchedIndicies = new ArrayList<>();

    while (j < list2.size()) {
        String codonj = list2.get(j);

        if (codoni.equals(codonj)) {
            a = Math.min(Math.abs(i - j), a);
            matchedIndicies.add(j);
        }
        j++;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < matchedIndicies.size(); k++) {
        int deviation = k == matchedIndicies.size() - 1 ? minDeviation : 0;
        System.out.println("[ " + i + " ] = [ " + matchedIndicies.get(k) + " ]" + deviation);
    }
    a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

If try to write to programmer-wise, optimized thing the first thing comes to my mind is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int lastIndex = -1;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String codon = list.get(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
        if (codon.equals(list2.get(j))) {
            if (lastIndex > -1) {
                System.out.println("[ " + i + " ]" + " = " + "[ " + lastIndex + " ]" + 0);
            }
            lastIndex = j;
            min = Math.min(Math.abs(i - j), min);
        }

        if (j == list2.size() - 1) {
            System.out.println("[ " + i + " ]" + " = " + "[ " + lastIndex + " ]" + min);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to give 0 when there's a repetition but when there's no repetition I want it to give i - j. so im asking if there's any way to do that... And I can't see the correct algorithm that u mentioned it in ure answer.

Comment: Okay, then your solution is totally of the track since it writes the results as soon as they are calculated. I mean you should only write the result at the end of the loop.

Comment: im trying to find the total of all deviations by adding them all together and returning an int.. so that's y I had the idea to put all repetitions to 0

Comment: btw your code is giving a total of 9 instead of 8. check ```[ 4 ] = [ 1 ]3```

Comment: I told you, i implemeneted from the little information i had from your code, now check i think its corrected. Or modified.

Comment: some further optimization droping using list.  optimized for arraylists.